# POST to test servers from production

Tags: post, replication

I have a production web app receiving data from a 3rd party via POST. 
I would like to have that same data POSTed to my staging server as well.  How can I do that most efficiently? I think I may be able to configure the load balancer to POST to both servers, but my dev ops guy says its not recommended. Do I have any other sensible option aside from POSTing from my production host to my staging host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your load balancer can forward it to the staging system too (without returning the response from that system of course), that's the cleanest way.

You could also have the production system simply log all those requests e.g. to a database and then have a script retrieve the requests from the database and POST them to the staging system.

Any other way would require you to add code to your production system to forward those requests - and that's nothing I'd want in a production system.